# Matching list of regular expression to list of strings

Tags: python, regex

I'm working on matching a list of regular expressions with a list of strings. The problem is, that the lists are very big (RegEx about 1 million, strings about 50T). What I've got so far is this:

```
reg_list = ["domain\.com\/picture\.png", "entry{0,9}"]

y = ["test","string","entry4also_found","entry5"]

for r in reg_list:
    for x in y:
        if re.findall(r, x):
            RESULT_LIST.append(x)
            print(x)
```

Which works very well logically but is way to unefficient for those number of entries. Is there a better (more efficient) solution for this?

Comment: You don't need to use `re.findall()`, just `re.search()`.

Comment: `entry{0,9}` is probably not what you have in mind. Should be `entry[0-9]` probably

Comment: you can try `h = re.compile('hello'), h.match('hello world')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `any()` to test if any of the regular expressions match, rather than looping over the entire list.

Compile all the regular expressions first, so this doesn't have to be done repeatedly.

```
reg_list = [re.compile(rx) for rx in reg_list]

for word in y:
    if any(rx.search(word) for rx in reg_list):
        RESULT_LIST.append(word)
```

Comment: Is it possible to get the index of the matched regex pattern in the reg_list?

Comment: There's no built-in function for finding the first index matching a predicate, you'll need to write a loop using `enumerate()`.

Answer (score 2):

The only enhancements that come to mind are

- Stopping match at first occurrence as `re.findall` attempts to search for multiple matches, this is not what you are after
- Pre-compiling your regexes.

```py
reg_list = [r"domain\.com/picture\.png", r"entry{0,9}"]
reg_list = [re.compile(x) for x in reg_list]            # Step 1

y = ["test","string","entry4also_found","entry5"]

RESULT_LIST = []
for r in reg_list:
    for x in y:
        if r.search(x):                                 # Step 2
            RESULT_LIST.append(x)
            print(x)
```

Comment: you can also pre-compile the regexes (even if there's a cache)

Comment: Thank you, Jean-François, it may indeed boost the search speed, though the warm-up will take a tad more tiime.

Answer (score 1):

```
python -m timeit -s "import re" "re.match('hello', 'hello world')"
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.82 usec per loop

$ python -m timeit -s "import re; h=re.compile('hello')" "h.match('hello world')"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.26 usec per loop
```

So, if you are going to be using the same regex a lot, it may be worth it to do re.compile (especially for more complex regexes).